# Using for, .split() and if

Tags: python, for-loop

**What I wrote:**

```py
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence' 
x = st.split()
print(x)
for letter in st:
  if letter=='s':
    print(letter)
```

Please help with this question. I'm new to Python. I've tried thinking, but I don't seem to have cracked the logic part of the code

Answer (score 3):

```
x = st.split()
for word in x:
    if word.startswith("s"):
        print(word)
```

That should work

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with your existing code is that you split the string  `st` into a list where each word is kept as a separate item (which you label `x`) — but then you go ahead to iterate over your original string `st` rather than the list-of-words `x` that you've just created.

4 different solutions for you that are identical in what they accomplish, all of which iterate over a list of words created by `st.split()`, and all of which use the string method `.startswith()` to filter out the words that do not start with "s".

Solution 1: use if-logic to filter the for-loop

```
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'

for word in st.split():
    if word.startswith('s'):
        print(word)
```

Solution 2: use a generator expression

```
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'

for word in (w for w in st.split() if w.startswith('s')):
    print(word)
```

Solution 3: use the `filter` function with a `lambda` function:

```
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'

for word in filter(lambda w: w.startswith('s'), st.split()):
    print(word)
```

Solution 4: use the `filter` function with `operator.methodcaller`:

```
from operator import methodcaller

st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'

for word in filter(methodcaller('startswith', 's'), st.split()):
    print(word)
```